# Entity Framework code first and membership tables on LocalDb

Tags: entity-framework-4, connection-string, localdb

**1.  If I create new MVC project it has default connection string :**

```
< add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial
Catalog=aspnet-OneVeryBad.Web-20130301153805;Integrated   
Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-OneVeryBad.Web-20130301153805.mdf" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**2.  I create my context inheriting from DbContext :**

```
public class BadContext : DbContext
{
    public BadContext() : base("BadContext")
    {
    }

    /* DbSets */
}
```

**3. Change connection string name to BadContext to work with EF:**

```
< add name="BadContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial 
Catalog=aspnet-OneVeryBad.Web-20130301153805;Integrated 
Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-OneVeryBad.Web-
20130301153805.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**Now I sucessfully can store data to LocalDb, but cannot register users :**

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.  Description:
>   An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: CREATE DATABASE
>   permission denied in database 'master'.

unless I change connection string back to original :

> < add name="DefaultConnection" ...

I see my context tables and membership tables in local db through VS server explorer.
But cannot make membership work with EF connection string. How can I solve this ?
Originally I want to store all tables in localdb so that its always with me in the project wherever I go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the connection string name in the InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs file under the Filters folder.

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", 
    "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

To:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("BadContext", "UserProfile", 
    "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

Did it occur to you to maybe use the Find In Files function to search for "DefaultConnection"?

Comment: Thanks, I had to change this one as well : public class UsersContext : DbContext
    {
        public UsersContext()
            : base("BadContext")
        {
        }
}